# How to match two fields in an SQL query?

Tags: sql

Please correct the query.

It is working but it gives the wrong result, I have database tables that look like this.

```
[3rdi_EventsRolePrice] :-EventID, RoleID, RolePrice
[3rdi_EventsRolePrice]:- FirstName, LaastName And EventID
```

I want to get `FirstName`, `LastName`, `RoleID` by joining these two, and I am passing an event value as a parameter which is 13 in my case just for getting result.

```
SELECT ep.FirstName, ep.LastName, erp.RoleID 
from [3rdi_EventParticipants] ep,[3rdi_EventsRolePrice] erp
WHERE  ep.EventID==erp.EventID and erp.EventID='13'
```

I want to match where these two things "ep.EventID==erp.EventID" are equal, and their value is also 13. My query is also working syntaxically correct but I get a thoroughly wrong result.

Comment: Which kind of Database System is this, where == is syntactically correct?

Comment: i removed that. Bu mistake i put that

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
 ep.FirstName,
 ep.LastName,
 erp.RoleID

 FROM [3rdi_EventParticipants] ep
 INNER JOIN [3rdi_EventsRolePrice] erp
 ON  ep.EventID = erp.EventID 
 WHERE erp.EventID='13'
```

I think it will work..

Answer (score 1):

`ep.EventID==erp.EventID` to `ep.EventID=erp.EventID`